# Applet causing error

Tags: javascript, firefox, applet

I add an applet to the html page in my extension. The following line of code raises an exception:

```
    try {
        document.Applet.isActive();
    }
    catch(e) {
        setTimeout(doingSomeThing(),200);
        return;
    }
```

> Error: Attempt to call a default method on object with no invokeDefault method

And after a while:

> TypeError: document.Applet.isActive is not a function

I am testing the extension on different OS and firefox versions for deployment. The above error occurred on Firefox 4.0 on a Mac OS X machine running Java 1.6.0_22.

It tested it with Java version 1.6.0_24 on Mac OS X and it worked fine.

Any ideas regarding this?

**Update:** I am attaching the Java console output on 1.6.0_22

```
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition value null
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
basic: Told clients applet is started
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_22
Using JRE version 1.6.0_22-b04-307-10M3261 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM User home directory = /Users/tomrTrace level set to 5: all… completed.
basic: Starting applet teardown
basic: Finished applet teardown
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is the HTML where this JS occurs (& I mean he HTML source)?  Better still, where is the URL we can visit to see the applet fail?  And if your answer to that is 'it is private', the implication is that the onus is on you to make a version of the applet and put it up somewhere that it is **public.**

Answer (score 2):

Have a close look over [Detect if an Applet is ready - Real's HowTo](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0176.html).  It seems more complicated than a single line of JavaScript.